# Write all record met criteria line by line in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

Please help me how to list all records meets criteria in text box (line by line) as the below code retrieve the first record only .

Note : i tried to enable multi lines in text box but an error appeared"Can't assign to read only property"

Any help please with amending the beloe code

```
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim sLine As String, sNewText As String

iFile = FreeFile

Open App.Path & "\text1.txt" For Input As #iFile
Do While Not EOF(iFile)
  Line Input #iFile, sLine
  If sLine Like "*TOTAL INTERCHANGE*" Then
  Text5.Text = sLine
  End If
Loop
Close
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out if your line is containing the string "TOTAL INTERCHANGE" You can also use `Instr` (don't worries, `Like` works also just fine).

```
If Instr(1, sLine, "TOTAL INTERCHANGE") > 0 Then
    Text5.Text = Text5.Text & sLine & vbCrLf
End If
```

Here is the reference and you can also quickly test it online:: [VBScript InStr Function](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp) (it is VBScript, not VB6 but it doesn't matter, it is identical)

Regarding the `MultiLine` property, you should set it in the VB6 IDE, not by code.

To the point:

please note that you shouldn't replace the whole content of the TextBox but appending the new lines at the end by keeping the actual content of the `TextBox` and just inserting a line break. This is what the `Text5.Text = Text5.Text & sLine & vbCrLf` does.

Comment: Thanks Learning and deblocker , its worked fine now .

Comment: I have another questions :
- How can take specific line from text box and include it in another one (e.g. I found a one record in second line and i need it to be shown in another text box)?
- I want to add another condition on the statement and print the results in begin of each row from the first statement , is it doable ?

Comment: You should create another thread for your other question since your original question has already been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post what's inside the text1.txt file? Also do you really need to check the sLine for something like TOTAL INTERCHANGE value? By the way you are just overwriting the value of text5.text everytime. It should be

```
Text5.Text = Text5.Text & sLine
```

OR

```
Text5.Text = Text5.Text & sLine & vbCrLf
```

Also, you should be able to set the MultiLine to true at design time with no problem.